# Running a hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, jar

It is the first time I'm running a job on hadoop and started from WordCount example. To run my job, I', using this command

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

and I think we should copy the jar file in /usr/local/hadoop . My first question is that what is the meaning of hadoop*examples*? and if we want to locate our jar file in another location for example /home/user/WordCountJar, what I should do? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think we should copy the jar file in /usr/local/hadoop
```

It is not mandatory. But if you have your jar at some other location, you need to specify the complete path while running your job.

```
My first question is that what is the meaning of hadoop*examples*?
```

**hadoop*examples*** is the name of your jar package that contains your MR job along with other dependencies. Here, ***** signifies that it can be any version. Not specifically 0.19.2 or something else. But, I feel it should be ***hadoop-examples-****.jar and not **hadoop*examples*.jar**

> and if we want to locate our jar file in another location for example
>   /home/user/WordCountJar, what I should do?

If your jar is present in a directory other than the directory from where you are executing the command, you need to specify the complete path to your jar. Say,

**bin/hadoop jar /home/user/WordCountJar/hadoop-*-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output**

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is that my jar file is created by netbeans and named WordCount.jar and when I use this command "bin/hadoop jar /home/user/WordCountJar/WordCount.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output" nothing happens.

Comment: No error message?No exception?What happens if you run it from NetBeans itself?

Comment: If I use this command: "bin/hadoop jar /home/user/WordCountJar/hadoop-*-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output" I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /home/w023vxt/hadoop-*-examples.jar
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)

Comment: If I use "bin/hadoop jar /home/user/WordCountJar/WordCount.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output" nothing happens.

Comment: Your jar is **WordCount.jar**, so no point in running **examples.jar**. Right click on WordCount.jar and click on properties to see where exactly this jar is located and then issue the command accordingly. BTW, what is your username??

Answer (score 1):

The *examples* is just wildcard expansion to account for different version numbers in the file name. For example: hadoop-0.19.2-examples.jar

You can use the full path to your jar like so:

bin/hadoop jar /home/user/hadoop-0.19.2-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output

Edit: the asterisks surrounding the word examples got removed from my post at time of submission.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but the problem is that nothing happened and the job did not run with no error. It was weird for me!